# Pytest fixtures do not work with python3.7

Tags: python, pytest

I was trying to figure this out for a long while but I can't see what I am doing wrong...

This is my code:

```
import pytest
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get Isilon quota report', conflict_handler='resolve')
quota_reporter.parse_argv(parser, justdef=True)


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def report_report_by_login():
    args = parser.parse_args(['--type=report', '--groupby=login'])
    res = quota_reporter.quota_reporter(args)
    return res.repcounters['rw']


class TestBasics():
    def test_runs_a_report(self):
        #        args = self.parser.parse_args(['--type=report', '--groupby=login'])

        #        jres = quota_reporter.quota_reporter(args)

        assert report_report_by_login > 0
```

(there are more tests following but they don't use the fixture so they work)

And this is the error I get (I am running "python3.7 -m pytest -k test_reporter.py -v")

```
self = <test_reporter.TestBasics object at 0x7fdd8a11cc18>

    def test_runs_a_report(self):
        #        args = self.parser.parse_args(['--type=report', '--groupby=login'])
    
        #        jres = quota_reporter.quota_reporter(args)
    
>       assert report_report_by_login > 0
E       TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'

test_reporter.py:22: TypeError
```

So it's as if pytest ignores the @pytest.fixture decorator.

I went through tons of online docs and they all say it should simply work.

Please help!

Oren

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just a wrong usage of autouse. Autouse means that the fixture runs on every test, however, it doesn't mean that the output of that fixture is magically injected into your test function. If you want the output, you have to use it explicitly like

```py
def test_runs_a_report(self, report_report_by_login):
    ...
```

otherwise, you will just refer to the function itself and not the output.

Comment: Good to hear. If any answer on StackOverflow is helpful for your question and solves it, feel free to accept it.